# cryptocode 2 columns

Tags: two-column, ieeetran, cryptocode

I am working with the cryptocode packet in a contribution with two columns on Overleaf. I have the following sample code, but I have some problem to fix the overlap with the second column. Here the example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb} % Math packages
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{dashbox}
\usepackage[
    n,
    operators,
    advantage,
    sets,
    adversary,
    landau,
    probability,
    notions,    
    logic,
    ff,
    mm,
    primitives,
    events,
    complexity,
    asymptotics,
    keys]{cryptocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}

    
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\title{Hello World}
\author{XXX,XXX
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem XXX, XXX  \protect\\
% note need leading \protect in front of \\ to get a newline within \thanks as
% \\ is fragile and will error, could use \hfil\break instead.
}% <-this % stops an unwanted space

}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Hello world
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
bla,bla,bla
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\dbox{%
\procedure{My Protocol}{%
 \textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob}  \\
 b \sample \bin \< \< \\
 \< \sendmessageright*{\text{send over } b} \<  \\
 \< \< \text{do something}    \\
 \<\< \dbox{\begin{subprocedure}\procedure{Subprotocol}{
 \< \< \textbf{Charlie}  \\
\text{something more} \< \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageright*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \< \text{some processing}  \\
 \< \< \text{more processing}  \\ 
 \< \sendmessageleft*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageright*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageleft*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
}\end{subprocedure}}  \\
 \< \sendmessageleft*{\text{send over sth. else}} \<   \\
 \text{finalize} \< \< }
}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: screenshot of my problem]

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full minimal example others can just copy and test as is. Not these sniplets.

Comment: Unrelated: it is not a good idea to use the `center` env to center a figure. The `center` end adds vertical space above and below its contents, so does the `figure` env, thus double space. The standard method is to replace `\begon{center}` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`

Comment: @daleif I followed your first suggestion and I modified the post. By the way I put the ```centering``` without solve my problem.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the comment it was not related to your problem. Note that in general `hyperref` needs to be loaded last.

Comment: Perhaps start by making sure the example you post here compiles without error. Compiles fine if I repalce `\dbox` by `\fbox` with no overlaps. **never ignore compilation errors**

Comment: Now it compiles fine but the overlap still remain (with ```\dbox``` you need to use the package ```dashbox```.

Comment: Please show an image of what you see? I see no obvious overlap.

Comment: @daleif yes of course...

Comment: why are you loading so many packages? you can not possibly be using them all. No document written this century should be using epsfig for example. But th eproblem seems unrelated to cryptocode you simply have text that is too wide for the column, ether use `figure*` so it spans both columns or use `\small` or `\tiny` as the first thing in the figure  or whatever is required to make it small enough to fit.

Comment: Lol, I forgot this was a twocolumn document. I get the same as the image

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the template is two columns and not just one. By the way, yes this is a suggestion.

Comment: Then du what David suggests use `figure*` instead, or spans both columns it will never fit into one column

Comment: If you have another suggestion to fit the figure into one column and adapts it, it's better.

Comment: @CipherX yes that is why I suggested changing `figure` to `figure*` changing  to `figure*` would do nothing in a one column style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the spacing between columns in a `\pseudocode` or `\procedure` command via the `colspace` option. Setting it to a negative space collapses the columns which, in particular for protocols, allows for more compact presentation. The following example is with `colspace=-1cm`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{dashbox}
\usepackage[
    n,
    operators,
    advantage,
    sets,
    adversary,
    landau,
    probability,
    notions,    
    logic,
    ff,
    mm,
    primitives,
    events,
    complexity,
    asymptotics,
    keys]{cryptocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\title{Hello World}
\author{XXX,XXX
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem XXX, XXX  \protect\\
% note need leading \protect in front of \\ to get a newline within \thanks as
% \\ is fragile and will error, could use \hfil\break instead.
}% <-this % stops an unwanted space

}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Hello world
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
bla,bla,bla
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\dbox{%
\procedure[colspace=-1cm]{My Protocol}{%
 \textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob}  \\
 b \sample \bin \< \< \\
 \< \sendmessageright*{\text{send over } b} \<  \\
 \< \< \text{do something}    \\
 \<\< \dbox{\begin{subprocedure}\procedure{Subprotocol}{
 \< \< \textbf{Charlie}  \\
\text{something more} \< \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageright*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \< \text{some processing}  \\
 \< \< \text{more processing}  \\ 
 \< \sendmessageleft*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageright*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageleft*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
}\end{subprocedure}}  \\
 \< \sendmessageleft*{\text{send over sth. else}} \<   \\
 \text{finalize} \< \< }
}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Protocol with collapsed columns]

Answer (score 1):

There's no chance the figure fits in one column. Use `figure*`.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{dashbox}
\usepackage[
    n,
    operators,
    advantage,
    sets,
    adversary,
    landau,
    probability,
    notions,    
    logic,
    ff,
    mm,
    primitives,
    events,
    complexity,
    asymptotics,
    keys]{cryptocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\title{Hello World}
\author{XXX,XXX
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem XXX, XXX  \protect\\
% note need leading \protect in front of \\ to get a newline within \thanks as
% \\ is fragile and will error, could use \hfil\break instead.
}% <-this % stops an unwanted space

}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Hello world
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
bla,bla,bla
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[tp]
\centering
\dbox{%
\procedure{My Protocol}{%
 \textbf{Alice} \< \< \textbf{Bob}  \\
 b \sample \bin \< \< \\
 \< \sendmessageright*{\text{send over } b} \<  \\
 \< \< \text{do something}    \\
 \<\< \dbox{\begin{subprocedure}\procedure{Subprotocol}{
 \< \< \textbf{Charlie}  \\
\text{something more} \< \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageright*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \< \text{some processing}  \\
 \< \< \text{more processing}  \\ 
 \< \sendmessageleft*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageright*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
 \< \sendmessageleft*[1.5cm]{\text{message}} \<  \\
}\end{subprocedure}}  \\
 \< \sendmessageleft*{\text{send over sth. else}} \<   \\
 \text{finalize} \< \< }
}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]